# Bootstrap 2.3.2 css is breaking page-break-before in Safari(?)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I'm trying to put some page breaks into a page with `page-break-before`.  The site is built around Bootstrap 2.3.2; what I have is working fine in Mac Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari (7.0.1).  A greatly stripped-down version of one of my pages (also available at http://sampleco.net/print.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Storyboards for  Project 1</title>
  <style>@import url("bootstrap.css");</style>
  <style type='text/css'>
        .vr_pagebreak {
                page-break-before: always;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_container" class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <section class="span12">
            <h1 class="page-header">A general page header</h1>

            <div class='vr_pagebreak'></div>
            <h2>Scene 741: Alice places the call</h2>
            <p>Something about the scene and image.</p>

            <div class='vr_pagebreak'></div>
            <h2>Scene 2314: Scene with no takes (2314)</h2>
            <p>Something about the scene and image.</p>
          </section>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(There are a few Drupalisms in here, left over from the original site, but not many at this point.) `bootstrap.css` is simply a copy of the Bootstrap 2.3.2 css file.  If it's removed from this page, my page breaks work correctly in Safari (as well as in other browsers).  FWIW, adding a bit of text to the `vr_pagebreak` divs has no effect, nor does putting the `vr_pagebreak` css into a `@media print` wrapper.

I've looked through the bootstrap code, and don't see anything that might be getting in the way.  Does any of this ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: The standard procedure for debugging CSS is to start stripping things away.  Just dumping Bootstrap all together is like jumping all the way to the end, but your problem is somewhere in the middle.  Also, an empty div is a pretty ugly way of going about adding styling (you couldn't put the class on the h2?  or given it a semantic name?).

Comment: Understood about both. I agree about the lameness of the div.vr_pagebreak; this is a replacement for a more useful block of stuff that I pruned out as part of getting rid of possibly interfering code on the page. So, yeah, in its current form it's lame, but it should still work.  As for dissecting the Bootstrap css file, I posted this query in the hope that it would trigger something in someone that would save me from hacking around in somebody else's code.  If that's what's needed, I'll get to it, but I thought I'd try asking here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So: A bit of stylesheet hacking later, and it appears that the culprit is in line 255 of bootstrap.css:

```
[class*="span"] {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

In the demo code above, if you remove `float: left`, Safari properly does the requested page breaking.  As a test, I can hack around it by adding to my page:

```
section.span12 {
    float: inherit;
}
```

Odd...  Thoughts on this are welcome.

Comment: This is still an issue with Bootstrap 3.x. Unfortunately, in my case, changing the float breaks the rest of it.